# How to transfer data from DLT to another application like CANoe via TCP\IP and vice versa

Tags: tcp, canoe, dlt-daemon

I am using 
GENIVI Diagnostic Log and Trace for my project.
I am now able to transfer the message from ECU to DLT viewer, but I want to forward the message received in DLT viewer to another application like Vector CANoe.
And transfer the data from CANoe to DLT and then transfer the data from DLT to my ECU application, does anybody knows this ??

Please find the below image for some more info

[DLT TO APPlication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrSGl.jpg)

The medium of connection is given in the above image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to ask on the GENIVI DLT mailing list: https://lists.genivi.org/mailman/listinfo/genivi-diagnostic-log-and-trace

Comment: Did you got feedback by mailing list? I think you have to create the IPC Interface between CANoe and DLT. I know CANoe offers several ways e.g. FDX Interface, COM, TCP Server/Client.